# Load Entities From Database Without Underlying Table In Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have class `A` and class`B` and they are mapped to their corresponding tables with individual associated hibernate mapping file. Now I have class `C` which is like:

```
public class C {

private A           a;

private List<B>     b;

public A getA() {
  return a;
}

public List<B> getB() {
  return b;
}

public void setA(A a) {
  this.a = a;
}

public void setB(List<B> b) {
  this.b = b;
}

}
```

Note that `A` and `B`, they have One-To-Many relation. Now I want to a load `C` class which has `A` as master field with a special identifier(e.g. 2) and it's details of class `B` Automatically. So far I have managed to create `C` firstly by loading `A` and set it into `C` and then load a list of `B` and also set it into `C` and finally get the result through this. But I'm looking for a solution more cleaner and sweeter than what I'm going through now.